# How can i timeout an error in Node with shelljs?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, node-webkit, node-modules

I am using shellJs with node webkit to work on an android tablet. what i want to do is use shelljs to Fastboot read a bootloader variable (product). But in Fastboot if no device is connected the return is "waiting-for-device" and the connection is left open.
   What i'd like to do is let this command run for up to 5 seconds, then if the output != 'Soho' throw an error and cancel function.

This is my current code

```
$('#fbbtn').click(function(){
    var getVar = terminal.exec('fastboot -i 0x1949 getvar product');
    var getSerial = terminal.exec('fastboot -i 0x1949 devices');
    var test getVar.output.match(/Soho/g);
    if(test=='Soho'){
         fbSerial=getSerial.output.substr(0,16);
                    }
    else alert('ERROR');
});
```

I know that exec from shelljs offers {async:true} but dont understand promises well, and cant find very good documentation about them. Hopefully someone can educate me a bit here

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your child process async, wait for 5 seconds and then kill it.

```
var getvar = terminal.exec('fastboot -i 0x1949 getvar product', { async: true });
getvar.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
   var product = data;
   //Use the aquired value here
});

setTimeout(function() {
     getvar.kill();
}, 5000);
```

you will have to listen for data like in my example, then check if it is your desired string or "waiting for device".